# The Librarian's labrynth

Tags: knowledge, mystery

You've entered a library. The library is known for its large capacity, yet small size. Inside, you are in a room about the same size as the outside. There is one window on each wall (This is a four-sided building), except the side with the door which leads outside. You cannot see anyone inside or outside of the building.

Examining this room shows you that the outside door is the only door in the building. Inside is a desk with three books, red, green, and blue respectively. Their titles are "FICTION," "NONFICTION," and "AUTHORS" respectively.

You hear footsteps from outside, and you see someone carrying a load of books away from the library. You try shouting, but the person is deaf. You really want to read, so you open the red, *fiction* book. Inside on every page is a picture of a red book, also titled "FICTION"

What are these books, and where did the man with the books come from?

Hints will be provided daily.

Daily Hint #1

> If you've ever played the classic video game, Myst, this should seem familiar.

Daily Hint #2

> You are in the foyer of the Library. That man bypassed it on his way out from somewhere...

Comment: Are you sure he opened the green book with the title "FICTION" because if this title is matched to the color then the title should be "NONFICTION"?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for letting me know of the error!

Comment: Are the three books the only books in the library, or are they the only ones of note?

Comment: Something makes no sense to me in the story, how I supposedly in the library hears the footsteps from the outside of a person who takes books from the library because if there is one door and the man took the books from the library so I had to meet him on the way before leaving and not only to hear his footsteps from outside, About the time, as well as how I am supposed to determine that the man is deaf, maybe he is only with headphones or something like that

Comment: The man who can't hear you isn't necessary, only to tell you that you aren't getting help from him.

Comment: Regarding the first daily hint, rot13("zlfg" fbhaqf yvxr "zlfgrel" juvpu vf n pbzzba gurzr bs obbxf). Does this mean anything? I presume it does, but I can't find an clear relation with it and the puzzle.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with it. @user477343

Comment: I suppose the word 'labrynth' in the title is meaningful and important. But is its spelling meaningful, too, or is it just a mistake? Shouldn't it read 'labyrinth'?

Comment: Nope, just a mistake.

Comment: This puzzle does not seem to be solvable without important external context. Ah, hence the knowledge tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A wild guess:

> The rest of the library is hidden in different dimensions, called Ages, like in the game Myst. The books are linking books that teleport you to the correct Age: red for the collection of fiction, green for the collection of non-fiction, blue for the catalog. There you can pick up the books you want and somehow teleport back (I assume you have to use your library card for that :-)), emerging right outside the library building.

Comment: Close... what are they called?

Comment: rot13(Ntrf) - I've updated the answer in case it is essential :-)

Comment: Not yet. That's where to, not hat the books are. What are they called?

Comment: I've mentioned rot13(yvaxvat obbxf) in the answer - I think that was the term in the game?

Comment: Congrats! You're the first one to get it right.