# What on Mars? (A Poem-based riddle)

Tags: riddle, poetry

I make your hair fall

Your heart begins to fall, too

But I don't cut them.

---

I can be a rock

In some places, I'm some dust

You won't live much more.

---

Uranium Mines

An underground toxic find

I destroy your brain.

---

What am I?

Hint is in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this

> [Radiation](https://phys.org/news/2016-11-bad-mars.html)?

I make your hair fall

> Hair falling out, as in from radiation/chemotherapy

Your heart begins to fall, too

> Radiation can cause heart failure

But I don't cut them.

> Radiation doesn’t cut either hair or heart

I can be a rock

> Radioactive rocks exist, since they are just rocks containing radium

In some places, I'm some dust

> Radioactive dust is otherwise known as nuclear fallout

You won't live much more.

> This tends to kill people reasonably quickly

Uranium Mines

> Uranium is radioactive

An underground toxic find

> Which can be toxic and found underground

I destroy your brain.

> Radiation in high doses can destroy the brain

The hint in the title

> Is related to the link in the original answer, noting that the lack of magnetosphere on Mars makes radiation exposure much, much worse there than on Earth.

Comment: Yes, the title was supposed to help in this, but also throw people off. Most people don't know that Mars' surface is radioactive. Sorry, Elon, your trip to Mars has been canceled.

Comment: Fun puzzle @CStafford-14! Thanks very much!!

Comment: Thanks! Check out my other puzzle if you're up for a challenge. Nobody has answered yet. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/the-librarians-labrynth