# The Librarian's Labyrinth - Part II

Tags: knowledge, mazes

If you haven't completed the first puzzle in this series, go check it out: [*The Librarian's Labyrinth - Part I*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/the-librarians-labrynth)

---

**Part Two**

You now know what these books are. You place your hand over the first page, then off you go! You arrive in the fiction section of the Library. So now that you're there, what do you do?

The library is *the* labyrinth. Now you understand why it was called *The Library of Labyrinths*. Now you need to figure out what the library has to offer. But how?

To solve this puzzle, you must navigate the labyrinth. It's a simple labyrinth, but you'll have to go back and forth between rows. You need:

- A device that supports .zip files
- A program that can decompress secure .zip files with a password
- A simple image viewer
- A simple text (.txt) viewer

You will use a simulated .zip labyrinth. Download [Labyrinth.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1idvPWffhkOs_c6ip2fTpbCooHFqAR_cl)
to get started. You'll find some stuff in the .zip file with some answers, so please, don't post any of the passwords in your comment as hints or in the open. Thanks!

Comment: soo many empty folders? or is it my zip's problem?

Comment: There are a few empty ones

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires downloading a binary file. Please see [Where should binary files be stored?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6070) (spoiler: binary files *shouldn't* be used at all!) - puzzles should be self contained, and should never require someone to download and open files of unknown provenance.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I assumed it was ok because I saw other questions using it. Would a link to an external page, say GitHub, be ok?

Comment: @CStafford-14 See the answer I linked in my earlier comment. We don't want to encourage users to open binary files of unknown provenance *regardless* of where they're hosted. Files hosted off-site have the added issue that they might vanish, rendering the puzzle broken, so we generally insist that puzzles be self-contained here on-site. Finally, we do try to enforce this; if there are puzzles with required non-image binaries that we've missed, please custom-flag them (or ping me in [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)) so we can address them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my partial answer, not sure if it's the end.

> https://send.firefox.com/download/1cf2d7a85c2a192b/#Kn0UDtpaHKT3dQfC8bywYw

SPOILER:

> slack seems to be corrupt.

Comment: Nice job! SLACK.txt has no purpose now but will come into play later. Try changing the extension.

Comment: Besides, you've reached the end of Part II. Everything should make sense and wrap up in or around Part II

Comment: @CStafford-14 I did rename it to what it should be.  It then won't open.  That's why I say its corrupted.

Comment: What did you rename it to?

Comment: I renamed it to slack.png

Comment: That should work... what does it open in? Try forcing it to open in your image viewer.

Comment: It doesn't.  I can't open it in any image viewer (paint, gimp, irfanview).  I'll try to download a fresh copy when I get home, but you try downloading the zip file from here and trying.