# The Librarian's Labyrinth - Part III

Tags: wordplay, cipher, story, knowledge

"This Library is HUGE!," You say aloud. You hear your voice echoing through the halls and nothing else. How could this be? Who comes here? You start examining the books on the shelves. It's just your run-of-the-mill selection of fiction books. None of them look familiar, though. You are on your way to where you had first appeared in the library. There are three linking books. Two with their pages torn out, one book with all of its pages - NONFICTION. You pull out your phone. No service. No WiFi. It's a complete dead zone. So, you decide to warp there.

---

The Nonfiction section is larger - exponentially so. Again, nobody is there. Now all of the linking books have their pages torn out. You frantically look around it, but just barely myst a note:

> I've hidden the pages in one of the isles, On a certain shelf, and between a few certain books on the shelf. Take a wild guess.

Bewildered, you try to understand the note. Where could these books be?

*Please provide an explanation for your answer.*

---

Hint 1:

> You're dating something...

Hint 2:

> You've myst the other hint.

Hint 3:

> You can find the answer in a search or on IGN.

Hint 4:

> You really want to be released.

Hint 5:

> Look for Myst. Just the first one.

Hint 6:

> [Check Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst)

Hint 7:

> You aren't looking for an aspect of gameplay.

Comment: associated with https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/the-librarians-labrynth and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83128/the-librarians-labyrinth-part-ii

Answer (score 1):

I think the location of the missing pages might be

> In the library on Myst Island, between the books of Sirrus and Achenar.

Reasoning

> The hints have very clearly pointed out that this is related to the game [Myst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst) 
>  In the [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/the-librarians-labrynth), the non-fiction book was the *green* book and, in the game Myst, the green book leads to K'veer, where Atrus was imprisoned in the game. I think that this means *you* are Atrus, here, and Achenar is the one who left the note, trapping you in K'veer. This would mean that this event happens just after Sirrus and Achenar implement their plan to trap you, Atrus.

Hint 1

> Atrus practises a craft known as the Art, which allows him to create portals to other worlds known as *Ages*.

Hint 2-3

> Related to the game Myst

Hint 4

> Just like Sirrus and Achenar, Atrus is imprisoned and wants to be released.

Hint 5-6

> Related to the game Myst.

Comment: You're very far away... Read the hints. But yes, this is Myst-related. And your info is correct.

Comment: @CStafford-14 I've updated my answer which I think might be closer at least to what's intended.

Comment: You're still just as far.

Comment: Also, yes, this is related to Myst, but only one aspect of it is needed (It's not a part of the gameplay). You may need to google it.